# Object that may contain objects of given interfaces

Tags: typescript

imagine you have three types of objects, for example:

```
interface A {
  testA: someDifferentType;
}

interface B {
  testB: someOtherType[];
}

interface C {
  testC1: string;
  testC2: number;
}
```

Now I have a root object that is an object that may include those 3 interfaces (but none is required)
So for example this is a valid object:

```
{
  root: {
    testB: [{...}],
    testC1: 'test',
    testC2: 123
  }
}
```

What kind of type or interface it should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you just need to define the object such that it is a union of the partial interfaces:

```
interface MyObj {
  root: Partial<A> & Partial<B> & Partial<C>
}

const myObj: MyObj = {
  root: {
    testB: [{...}],
    testC1: 'test',
    testC2: 123
  }
};
```

You can also combine them in a single partial type, i.e.:

```
interface MyObj {
  root: Partial<A & B & C>
}
```